# What is the name of this threaded tube with screws at each end?

Tags: bolts

I have been attempting to find the name of this object:

[image]

The website where I got the picture from calls them "barrel bolts", however searching for that name on shopping websites has not shown any similar parts.

Do you know of other names for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some call them female to female standoffs.   I know product recommendations are OT in answers, so I'm not recommending them, just including a couple of links that may help your search.

https://apexfasteners.com/fasteners/standoffs/female-female-standoffs

https://www.fastenal.com/product?query=female%20-%20female%20standoffs&fsi=1

Answer (score 12):

I have found a few alternate names:

- Threaded tube
- Binding screws
- Book screws
- Binding rivets
- Standoff
- (+ see comment)

Comment: also binder bolts and a curious one, sex bolts

Comment: @fred_dot_u sex bolts, aka chicago bolts, have a male side and a female side only.  OP's example might be "double chicago bolt"

Comment: We called them spacers when used to mount PCBs inside of cases.

Comment: @Turbo, a better term for that application is "standoff".

Comment: @isherwood nope

Comment: Ok. I've been building PCs since the 90s and no one that I've encountered calls them "spacers", including board literature. That's a very generic term, like calling a Mason jar a "container". You do you. :)

Comment: I've heard them called "Pillars" for PCB mounting, because they are often used to stack PCB's on top of each other, like floors in a building.

Comment: I don't know about this site specifically, but on most SE sites, saying "*(+ see comment)*" would be pointless, as comments can and do get deleted without warning. One main purpose of comments is to make suggestions for improving the answer. If you think any of them *do* improve the answer, incorporate them into the answer. And then flag the comments as no longer needed.

Comment: Pretty much every standoff / board-spacer (I've seen both terms used fairly equally) that I've ever seen has a hex-shank body, so that each end can be tightened/loosened independantly.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the closest I could find at the local hardware store (Menards) was "Threaded spacer"

[image: threaded spacer item]

Not exact but you can also maybe use:

- "Binding Posts", "Screw Posts", or "Post with Screw". One side is fixed while the other side is threaded.

[image: binding post image]

- "Coupling Nut". Both sides are threaded, but they're usually chunkier for the given diameter

[image: coupling nut image]

Comment: slightly tangential, but worth noting: smaller format hardware stores (Like Ace, or-- if you happen to live in Minneapolis-- Jerry's Do It Best) will often have a lot of really obscure hardware that the big box places (Menards included) don't carry. Their prices are usually quite reasonable, too. Those are always my first stop for this sort of item. That said, Menard's also carries an impressive number of weird hardware items. Either option is almost always better than the Big Orange Place.

Answer (score 3):

1. "Inter Screws"
2. "Cabinet Joining Bolts" (usually much shorter than these.)
3. "Cabinet Connectors"

The end pieces on their own, something like "Socket Barrel Nuts"

If searching for them, I think the key word is "Connector" thought that will also tend to display "Furniture Connector Bolts" or "Worktop Connector Bolts", both of which are rather different items.

Answer (score 1):

The right name is Patent bolt(s).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What is the source of your information that makes this the "right" answer? I've heard all the other terms in the other answers, but never "Patent bolts"...

Comment: A quick googling suggests this is another name for chicago bolts, and is missing the double-sided nature that OP is searching for.